# Perform calculations and new dataframe from original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataframe, df, where I would like to perform calculations and create new fields from.

**Data**

```
l_re date_re val_re id_re    u_re pos_re  l_d date_d val_d  id_d      u_d
c    q321   10      c_q321_1  ok   160    c   q321   20    c_q321_1   hi
c    q321   20      c_q321_2  cool 160    c   q321   10    c_q321_2   hi
b    q321   5       b_q321_1  sure 50     NaN NaN    NaN   NaN        NaN           
NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN  NaN    c   q422   5     c_q422_1   red
NaN NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN  NaN    c   q422   15    c_q422_2   blue
```

**Desired**

```
lo  date    consumed    retro   final   space
c   q321    30          30      0       160
b   q321    5           0       5       49
```

**Doing**

1. I am trying to group by l_re and date_re and then sum val_re and create a ‘consumed’ column and then sum val_d and create a ‘retro’ column (group by l_d and date_d)
2. I am also trying to create a ‘final’ column which then subtracts the newly created ‘consumed’ from the newly created ‘retro’ column
3. Finally I am trying to group by **pos_re, l_re and date_re** and subtract the count of **id_re** from **pos_re** and add the count of id_d.  This is the 'space' column

for 'c', there are 2 counts of 'id_re' and there are 2 counts of  'id_d'

for 'b', there is 1 count of 'id_re', and 0 counts for 'id_d'

**Step 3 example**

(160 - 2) + 2 = 160

(50  - 1)  + 0  = 49

```
      step1 = df.groupby(['l_re','date_re']).agg({'val_re': 'sum'})
      step2 = df['final'] = df['consumed'] - df['retro'].astype(int)


      step3 = df['space'] = df.groupby(['pos_re', 'l_re', 'date_re']).transform('sum')

              df['space'] = (df['pos_re'] - df['id_re'] + df['id_d'])
```

*Step 3 involves subtracting and adding*

I am able to perform some of the transformations individually, but not sure how to merge all the steps smoothly together. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: IIUC In step 3 you are substracting pos_re and consumed then you are adding it again then what is sense of substraction...I mean then why you are substracting?

Comment: from where these numbers comes that you are adding?

Comment: @Anurag 160 and 50 are from 'pos_re' column 
There are 2 counts of 'id_re' from group c and there is one count of 'id_d' from group b

Comment: yup I got this but I am asking for the addition part that you are adding 2 and 0 so those numbers comes from where?

Comment: 2  is the count when c is grouped by pos_re', 'l_re', 'date_re' and the other 2 is the count when  'l_d', 'date_d' is grouped. b has 1 when grouping  pos_re', 'l_re', 'date_re' and  0 when grouping  'l_d', 'date_d'  since it has a NaN record

Comment: Are you sure you want to group by 'pos_re'? If pos_re=160 and pos_re=150 for (c   q321), what the output should be? A third line in your desired output?

Comment: I wish to group by, because 160 is uniquely tied to c - and 50 is uniquely tied to b

Comment: So group by (pos_re, l_re, date_re) is same as group by (l_re, date_re), isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
def f(x):
    d = {'consumed': [x['val_re'].sum()],
         'retro': [x['val_d'].sum()],
         'final': [x['val_re'].sum() - x['val_d'].sum()],
         'space': [x['pos_re'].mean() - x['id_re'].count() + x['id_d'].count()]}
    return pd.DataFrame(d)
```

```
>>> df.groupby(['l_re', 'date_re']).apply(f).reset_index()
  l_re date_re  level_2  consumed  retro  final  space
0    b    q321        0       5.0    0.0    5.0   49.0
1    c    q321        0      30.0   30.0    0.0  160.0
```

Comment: @Lynn. I don't understand why you choose the complex solution rather than a simple one?

Comment: Yes I do see now that this is simpler. You’ve created a function and then applied the function to the second line of code. I would have to try on my full dataset. The first solution worked on both. I need to test out my full dataset, as this definitely works on the sample dataset provided.

Comment: Let me test in the morning

Comment: your code works well. I have created a new post similar to this one. Could you please look at this if you can. I am still researching

Answer (score 1):

Step 3 not clear

```
s=df.groupby(['l_re','date_re']).agg(consumed =('val_re','sum'),retro =('val_d','sum')).reset_index()
s['final']=s['consumed'].sub(s['retro'])
```

Comment: ok thank you this solves the first 2 steps